# por que algunos archivos no redireccionan?

Tags: php, html, sql

Instale la copia de un sistema web en un servidor nuevo con sus respectiva base de datos. Al hacer pruebas me percate que algunos archivos no me direccionan al que debe de ser o se redireccionan a si mismos.

No modifique nada de codigo...

porque pasa esto?

Comment: ¿Has comprobado si están en la misma ruta que estaban anteriormente en el servidor anterior?

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente el servidor anterior usaba redirecciones de URL y routing, lo cual requiere que el servidor web también tenga activadas algunas configuraciones específicas para reescritura de URLs.

En tu instalación nueva hay configuraciones de reescritura de URL distintas del servidor original.